# Joomla - Check if an Article is Updated

Tags: joomla2.5, updates, article

I need to collect the articles that has been recently updated. And I'm not sure how to do this as I'm fairly new to this CMS.

I Checked the 'j_content' column in database if it already have some kind of flag for updated article, but i failed to find any such thing.

Any possible lead to this could be helpful.

Comment: The content table has a column called `modified` you should be able to query this column to either see the last modified articles (just by sorting) or get articles updated since a certain time.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the latest articles by modified column in xxx_content table.

In your database execute below query (may be using phpMyAdmin)

```
select * from xxx_content order by modified desc;
```

if you would like to limit the result to say a month of articles:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    xxx_content 
where 
    modified >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') 
order by 
    modified desc;
```

Replace xxx with your table prefix